# Formsy react validation ( server response )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formsy-react

I'm using formsy-react ( for client validation ). It works perfect for now, but i have to pass error if something bad on server side.

Is it possible to take response when form was submitted? Get response from server?

Or how i can achieve that without formsy ? 
I'm new in react 
Thanks for help. 
Appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy task with `Formsy-react`. You could use `updateInputWithError` method ([Documents here](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md#updateinputswitherrorerrors)) or use `invalidateForm` which is passed as a parameter of `onValidSubmit`.

Example with `onValidSubmit` :

```
const App = React.createClass({
  ...
  submit(model, resetForm, invalidateForm) {
    this.callServerAPI()
        .then(...)
        .catch((serverErrors) => {
           // serverErrors should be 
           // { Name: 'Name is too long', Class: 'Class is not valid' }
           invalidateForm(serverErrors); // Just call invalidateForm
        });
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Formsy.Form ref="form" onValidSubmit={this.submit}>
        <MyInput name="Name" title="Name" value={user.name} />
        <MyInput name="Class" title="Class" value={user.class} />
        <div className="buttons">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </Formsy.Form>
    );
  }
});
```